# STORE GIVING ERROR when we use PIGSTORAGE

Tags: apache-pig

STORE data INTO 'tmp/data' USING pigstorage('|');

Error.orgapache.pig.tools.grant.grant error 1070: could not resolve pigstorage using imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pigstorage **P and S** should be capital letter. change like this it will work.

```
 STORE data INTO 'tmp/data' USING PigStorage('|');
```

Comment: Hi Siva..thanks for the reply.I figure it out in morning and got the result.Thanks again for the reply.